# Nullpointerexception: display data with a arrayadapter in a listview

Tags: android, arrays, database, sqlite, android-arrayadapter

Hy guys!

My problem is that i get a NullpointerException while creating the database. I think i am getting in trouble with the constructor or something else because th errer occurs at line 64 at the DatabaseHelper and this is: this.getReadableDatabase();
And my second error occurs in Activity verbindung at line 32 with:   myDbHelper.createDataBase();

Here is my Activity with the Arrayadapter:

public class PlanAusgabeSubActivity extends Activity {

```
Intent intent;
ListView lvList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.planausgabelayout);

    getRoute();
}

public void getRoute() {
    lvList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvList);
    Verbindungen verbindungen = new Verbindungen(this);

    ArrayAdapter<DefineRoute> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DefineRoute>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,verbindungen.getVerbindungen());

    lvList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

here is my databasehelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/at.atn.android/databases/";

    public static String DB_NAME = "db.sqlite3";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            //do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }
```

Activity Verbindung:

```
public class Verbindungen {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    LinkedList<DefineRoute> route;
    DefineRoute[] routeArray;
    Context context;

    DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    public Verbindungen(Context context) {
        route = new LinkedList<DefineRoute>();
        this.context = context;
    }

    public DefineRoute[] getVerbindungen() {

        try {

            myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }

        db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        // Alle Daten der Datenbank abrufen mithilfe eines Cursors
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT strftime('%H:%M', f.abfahrt) AS Abfahrt," +
                "strftime('%H:%M', f.ankunft) AS Ankunft," +
                "strftime('%H:%M', strftime('%s',f.ankunft)- strftime('%s',f.abfahrt), 'unixepoch') AS Dauer," +
                "r.name AS Route," +
                "count(u.fahrt_id) AS Umstiege " +
                "FROM scotty_fahrt f " +
                "JOIN scotty_haltestelle start ON f.start_id = start.id " +
                "JOIN scotty_haltestelle ziel ON f.ziel_id = ziel.id " +
                "JOIN scotty_route r ON f.route_id = r.id " +
                "LEFT OUTER JOIN scotty_umstiegsstelle u ON f.id = u.fahrt_id " +
                "WHERE start.name = 'Linz/Donau Hbf (Busterminal)' " +
                "AND ziel.name = 'Neufelden Busterminal (Schulzentrum)' " +
                "GROUP BY u.fahrt_id",null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int i=0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            //in this string we get the record for each row from the column "name"
            i++;
        }
        routeArray = new DefineRoute[i];
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int k =0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            routeArray[k] = new DefineRoute(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3));
            k++;

        }
        //here we close the cursor because we do not longer need it
        //}
        cursor.close();
        myDbHelper.close();

        return routeArray;

    }
```

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Move

`DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);`

into your `Verbindungen` constructor. The `context` is not defined.

```
DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

public Verbindungen(Context context) {
    route = new LinkedList<DefineRoute>();
    this.context = context;
}
```

Should be

```
DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = null;

public Verbindungen(Context context) {
    route = new LinkedList<DefineRoute>();
    this.context = context;
    myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}
```

Comment: but one more question, when i am diasplaying it. My output is [packagenam].DefineRoute@4050e7b8?

Comment: why i don't get data from the database?